# Entity Framework - Db design suggestion

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have two models with many-to-many relationship:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; } = new List<Hobby>();
}
```

and

```
public class Hobby
{
    public int HobbyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
}
```

In other words a person may have several hobbies and a hobby could interest many persons.

Now I have below model which has many-to-many relationship with the Person model:

```
public class Activity
{
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
}
```

I have setup my Blazor WASM project and I have populated all the tables using EntityFramework Code First.
Here is how my data structure in the database looks like:

1. I have populated the Hobbies table with example data
2. I have populated the Persons table with example data, and assigned at least one or more hobby from the table above to each person.
3. I have implemented all CRUD operations for the two above processes and everything works just fine.

Where am I stuck and what am I trying to achieve?
I want to create a new activity with persons based on hobbies.
Let's say that my Hobbies table contains the following hobbies:

- Art
- Sports
- Photography

And my Persons table contains the following persons:

- Clara
- Mathew
- Jack
- Rose

I would like to create new activities like below:

[image]

The problem is that with my current design of the database, I can't keep track of what specific Hobby was chosen from each Person to create the Activity. I need a way to reflect that in the database.

For instance, if I browse my activity View.razor, the Hobby field in the activity would list all the hobbies and not that specific one I created the activity based upon.

Please feel free to ask for more details as I may have not been sufficiently clear about everything.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your models so your persons also track activity. or you can just make multiple queries...

This has nothing to do with blazor/wasm, you need to look up efcore many-to-many: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many

Comment: Can you please provide an example or elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

Please add a table: PersonHobby.

```
public class PersonHobby
{
    public int PersonHobbyId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
    public virtual ICollection<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; } = new List<Hobby>();
}
```

Remove direct FK relationship between Hobby and Person Table. Use new PersonHobby Table to hold that relationship. Thereafter, you link Activity table with the new PersonHobby table. This will allow you to create Activity linked with array of Hobby and Persons (Activity X => {Art, Clara, Mathew}; Activity Y => {Art, Piano, John}) and so on. However, do you want Art/Piano as part of same collection as John/Clara?? However, I assume this is what you are looking at.

BTW, your Activity table listed above conveys that Hobby has kinda 1:1 relationship with Activity. If that is what you want then you do not need Activity table and can rename Hobby as Activity (Art is X, Sports is Y etc.). You list headings that way then. Hope it helps.